# Is this a nasty global hash?

Tags: ruby, global-variables

I heard that certain practices such as global variables are often frowned upon. I would like to find out if it is generally also frowned upon to place a hash at the level shown below. If so, how should it be done so that it is smiled upon?

```
class Dictionary
  @@dictionary_hash = {"Apple"=>"Apples are tasty"}

  def new_word
    puts "Please type a word and press enter"
    new_word = gets.chomp.upcase
    puts "Thanks. You typed: #{new_word}"
    @@dictionary_hash[new_word] = "#{new_word} means something about something. More on this later."
    D.finalize
    return new_word.to_str
  end
  def finalize
    puts "To enter more, press Y then press Enter. Otherwise just press Enter."
    user_choice = gets.chomp.upcase
    if user_choice == "Y"
      D.new_word
    else
      puts @@dictionary_hash
    end
  end

  D = Dictionary.new
  D.new_word
end
```

Comment: If you are asking out of curiosity, then, what you are doing seems to be bad design - it will be in any language

Comment: Note that `new_word` calls `finalize` which in turn calls `new_word` - you might want to use a loop instead.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you should be using a class variable at all. With a class variable, you'd be sharing the words and definitions between all Dictionaries. The point of having an instance of a Dictionary is to have definitions in that instance that are different from the definitions in another instance. Look at ThomasSevestre's answer below for using an instance variable.

Comment: I can't find any global variable in your code.

Comment: local variable `new_word` (within the method body of `new_word`) is always a string. I don't understand why you have `to_str` in `return new_word.to_str`.

Comment: Your hash is a class variable, not a global variable.. Global variables look like this: `$global_variable`, this might help you a little bit.. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm

Answer (score 3):

You should check the difference between:

- global, class and instance variables
- class and instance methods

Your are close to a working exemple with an instance variable:

```
class Dictionary

  def initialize
    @dictionary_hash = {"Apple"=>"Apples are tasty"}   
  end

  def new_word
    puts "Please type a word and press enter"
    new_word = gets.chomp.upcase
    puts "Thanks. You typed: #{new_word}"
    @dictionary_hash[new_word] = "#{new_word} means something about something. More on this later."
    finalize      
    new_word
  end

  def finalize
    puts "To enter more, press Y then press Enter. Otherwise just press Enter."
    user_choice = gets.chomp.upcase
    if user_choice == "Y"
      new_word
    else
      puts @dictionary_hash
    end
  end
end

d = Dictionary.new
d.new_word
```